# Multi node graph projection gds.graph.project.cypher for similarity algoritm in cypher

Tags: database, graph, neo4j, cypher, graph-databases

I want to understand which beers have the similar reviews with a specific beers, and for that i am using Graph db, I am using cypher to queries the data. I am trying to project a graph and run in through the algorithm to receive similar nodes.

```
CALL gds.graph.project.cypher(
'my', 
"MATCH (n) where head(Labels(n))='BEERS' or head(Labels(n))='REVIEWS' 
RETURN id(n) AS id",
"MATCH (b:BEERS {name:'Super Bock Stout'})-[n:REVIEWED]->(r:REVIEWS)-[]->(u:USER)<-[]-(r1:REVIEWS)<-[]-(b1:BEERS)
WHERE id(b)<>id(b1)
AND r.look = r1.look
AND r.taste = r1.taste
AND r.overall = r1.overall
AND r.smell = r1.smell
AND r.score = r1.score
AND r.feel = r1.feel
RETURN id(r) AS source, id(r1) AS target, count(*)")
```

I try to build the projection using this code, I understood that cypher similarity algorithm decide the similarity base on common nodes that both source and target are connected, I created the relationship accordingly to that but still after running through the algorithm I received empty brackets

```
CALL gds.graph.project.cypher(
'my1', 
"MATCH (n) where head(Labels(n))='BEERS' or head(Labels(n))='REVIEWS' 
RETURN id(n) AS id",
"MATCH (b:BEERS)-[n:REVIEWED]->(r:REVIEWS)
RETURN id(b) AS source, id(r) AS target")
```

This is the algorithm that I am using. It would be really helpful if someone could explain what I am doing wrong.

I tried to do different approaches, different nodes, different relationships between nodes, I tried to apply different filter, but unfortunately not success until now.

Comment: `gds.graph.project` is not yet the algorithm, it is only the projection, basically the preparation for the algorithm. You need to call an algorithm with your projected graph, e.g. `CALL gds.nodeSimilarity.stream('myGraph') YIELD node1, node2, similarity`

Comment: Are you sure yoi have reviews in the data from a single user that have all the five properties identical

Comment: Yes i am sure of that, i can check it through simple queries